# Doctrine ODM Get By Id with mixed type

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a collection of mixed type like defined here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/07/20/mixing-types-of-documents.html

```
/**
 * @Document(collection="my_documents")
 * @DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"article"="Article", "album"="Album"})
 */
class Article
{
    // ...
}
```

Album

```
/**
 * @Document(collection="my_documents")
 * @DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"article"="Article", "album"="Album"})
 */
class Album
{
    // ...
}
```

I would like to retrieve any object of that collection with a given Id.

Something like

```
$object = $dm->find(['Article','Album'], $id);
```

I can't use that because find take a Document Name. It would be :

```
$article = $dm->find('Article', $id);
$album = $dm->find('Album', $id);
```

I have tried to create my own query but it always return null.

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder(['Article', 'Album']);
$qb
   ->elemMatch(['id' => $id])
;
$result  = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to introduce a parent class from which both `Article` and `Album` extend. Thanks to that you'll also be able to specify `@DiscriminatorMap` once:

```
/**
 * @Document(collection="my_documents")
 * @DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"article"="Article", "album"="Album"})
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 */
abstract class Item {  }

/**
 * @Document()
 */
class Album extends Item { /* ... */ }

/**
 * @Document()
 */
class Article extends Item { /* ... */ }
```

Now whenever you would want to look for documents of both types at a same time you can use:

```
$item = $dm->find(Item::class, $id);
```

Depending on what is stored in the database, `$item` will come back either as an `Article` or an `Album`. Furthermore you can do the same with repository:

```
$items = $dm->getRepository(Item::class)->findAll();
```

Comment: Any Idea without inheritance?

Comment: Theoretically you could fetch data from MongoDB on your own (`DocumentManager::getDocumentCollection`) and then call Hydrator manually, but that seems to be an overkill